# How do you properly add a separate file to an Xcode project?

Tags: swift

The only other project I've worked on didn't need extra files. I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial, but autofill is acting sporadically. I think I'm adding a new file to the project incorrectly.

Here's what I did to add the file to follow along.

YouTube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcDBMMjj0wU&t=199s

Code:

```
import UIKit

class DrawExamples: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // context is the object used for drawing
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)

        /*
        //straight line
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 30, 30)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 320)
        */

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 130)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 180, 100)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 60)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 90, 130)


        //Actually draw the path
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The file is fine, the Swift version of the code is too old. Please look at the documentation of `CGContext` and `UIView` to figure out the proper syntax.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Thank you.